# functions processing not the last statement of a variable?

Tags: javascript, image

i working on this code that the objective is to: check if is a PNG, check if is 256X256, and transform img to base64 to upload to the server.

so if i select a 256 x 256 img it's loads but,if i load another img that is not a 256 x 256 after selecting a 256 x 256 it's loads and i don't know why!
[Video Showing](https://i.imgur.com/A83hozR.gifv)
How can i resolve it?

```js
function isFileImage(file) {
    const acceptedImageTypes = ['image/png'];

    return file && acceptedImageTypes.includes(file['type'])
}



function importFileandPreview() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  if (file) {
    //read img
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    //verify type
    var text = file.type;
    if (text === "image/png") {
      //load img
      reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        //put img on <img> src
        //console logs
        //console.log(preview);
        //console.log("pre_nat_height:"+preview.naturalHeight);
      // console.log("pre_nat_width:"+preview.naturalWidth);
       //technically check if img is 256 x 256
       var old = preview.src;
       preview.src = reader.result;
        if(preview.naturalHeight === 256 && preview.naturalWidth === 256){
          //create a hidden input (works but value is not from last img)
          var element = document.getElementById("imga");
            if(typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null){
            document.getElementById("imga").remove();
          }
            input = document.createElement('input');
            input.setAttribute("type","hidden");
            input.setAttribute("id","imga");
            input.setAttribute("name","img")
            input.setAttribute("value",preview.src);
            document.getElementById('count').appendChild(input);

            delete preview;
        }
        //else if img is not 256 x 256
        else {
          preview.src = old;
          alert("Must be a PNG and have 256px X 256px!");
          delete preview;
        }
      }, false);// i don't know why false but ye
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" accept="image/PNG" onchange="importFileandPreview()"><br>
<img src=" data:image/png;base64,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" height="256" width="256">
<form id="count">
</form>
```

Comment: That `false` you're wondering about has to do with whether the event is caught in the bubbling (`false`) or capturing (`true`) phase.

Comment: understood, i will see more about this phases

Comment: Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64617332/6313073), @Victor. I hope it helps 

Comment: @Angel, thanks that resolve my problem, and one more thanks for commenting my code, I really need to do it more 

Comment: I'm glad I could help, @Victor. You don't have to be as obsessed about commenting as I am but I suggest you do it more, indeed. Otherwise, since you're constantly growing as a programmer, you're soon going to have trouble understanding some of the code you wrote in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr:** You need to perform the check against the natural dimensions of the image inside the handler for the preview's `load` event.

---

The problem you're facing is a consequence of bad timing rather than poor logic. More specifically, it lies in that you set the new `src` of your preview and then check against the loaded image's natural dimensions ***synchronously***.

This approach is wrong because an image loads ***asynchronously*** and, therefore, your code doesn't wait for it to load before proceeding with your check. As a result, when, after selecting a valid image, you select an invalid one, you're still checking against the dimensions of the former as the latter hasn't yet loaded.

To correct this error, you have to perform your check inside the handler for the preview's `load` event, just as shown below.

**Working Snippet:**

*(I've rewritten the function to make it easier to read)*

```js
function isFileImage (file) {
    const acceptedImageTypes = ["image/png"];
    return file && acceptedImageTypes.includes(file["type"])
}

function importFileandPreview () {
    var preview = document.querySelector("img");
    var file    = document.querySelector("input[type=file]").files[0];
    var reader  = new FileReader();

    /* Terminate the function prematurely if the file isn't an image. */
    if (!isFileImage(file)) return;

    /* Load the file into the reader. */
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    /* Set the 'load' event of the reader. */
    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        /* Create a temporary image to use for the check to avoid flashing. */
        var tempPreview = new Image();

        /* Set the 'load' event of the temporary preview. */
        tempPreview.addEventListener("load", function () {
            /* Check whether the selected image isn't 256x256 pixels. */
            if (this.naturalHeight != 256 || this.naturalWidth != 256) {
                /* Alert the user. */
                alert("Must be a PNG and have 256px X 256px!");

                /* Restore the default src to the preview. */
                preview.src = preview.dataset.defaultSrc;

                /* Terminate the function prematurely. */
                return;
            }

            /* Set the result of the reader as the source of the preview. */
            preview.src = reader.result;

            /* Save the image to the form. */
            saveImageToInput(reader.result);
        });

        /* Set the result of the reader as the source of the image. */
        tempPreview.src = reader.result;
    });

    /* Save the default image in a data-* attribute to use again if needed. */
    preview.dataset.defaultSrc = preview.dataset.defaultSrc || preview.src;
}


function saveImageToInput (image) {
    /* Find the hidden input. */
    var input = document.getElementById("imga");

    /* Check whether the input doesn't exist. */
    if (!input) {
        /* Create a new hidden input. */
        input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("id", "imga");
        input.setAttribute("name", "img");
        input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");

        /* Place the input in the form. */
        document.getElementById("count").appendChild(input);
    }

    /* Save the image as the input's value. */
    input.setAttribute("value", image);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" accept="image/PNG" onchange="importFileandPreview()"><br>
<img src=" data:image/png;base64,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" height="256" width="256">
<form id="count">
</form>
```

**Notes:**

1. It's a good idea to use a temporary preview to check if the selected image fulfils your criteria because, if you load it in the visible preview and then alert the user, the loaded image will show.
2. `delete preview`: Don't do this. Variables in JavaScript aren't supposed to be deleted like this.
3. The third argument passed to `addEventListener` determines whether the event is caught in the bubbling or the capturing phase. By default, it's `false`, so you can omit it.